# Get all documents from an index - elasticsearch

Tags: rest, api, elasticsearch

How can I get all documents from an index in elasticsearch without determining the size in the query like

```
GET http://localhost:8090/my_index/_search?size=1000&scroll=1m&pretty=true'-d '{"size": 0,"query":{"query_string":{ "match_all" : {}}}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the ES [scan query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html), `size` parameter is not just the number of results:

> The size parameter allows you to configure the maximum number of hits
>   to be returned with each batch of results. Each call to the scroll API
>   returns the next batch of results until there are no more results left
>   to return, ie the hits array is empty.

To retrieve all the results you need to do subsequent calls to the API in the manner described in the aforementioned documentation, or to use some ready made implementation, like there is in [python](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=scroll#scan). Here is an example script to dump resulting jsons on stdout:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan
import json

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('https://localhost:8090')
es_response = scan(
    es,
    index='my_index',
    doc_type='my_doc_type',
    query={"query": { "match_all" : {}}}
)

for item in es_response:
    print(json.dumps(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest documentation, you will have to use the search_after parameter to retrieve records more than 10,000 from an index. take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after